# How to separate the values from two dimension array in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
jQuery.get("ChkNewRspLive.php?lastmsgID=" + n, function(newitems){
     //some code to separate values of 2d array.
     $('#div1').append(msgid);
     $('#div2').append(rspid);  
});
```

Let's say the value of `newitems` is `[["320","23"],["310","26"]]`

I want to assign "`320`" and "`310`" to `var msgid`.

I want to assign "`23`" and "`26`" to `var rspid`.

How to do that?

I tried to display newitems and the output is "Array". I tried to display newitems[0] and  the output is blank.

If I redeclare var newitems = [["320","23"],["310","26"]]; it works. So I guess the variable newitems from jQuery.get is something wrong. Is it I cannot pass the array from other page to current page through jQuery directly?

Regarding the array on other page, if `echo json_encode($Arraytest);` the output is `[["320","23"],["310","26"]]` but if `echo $Arraytest;` the output is `Array`. How do I pass the array from other page to currently page by jQuery.get?

Comment: I don't understand: you want to assign BOTH values (e.g. 320 and 310) to one variable (in this case msgid)?  Do you want them in an array or what?

Comment: yes, I want them in an array of msgid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't totally understand the question but I'm going to assume you want the values in an array, as two values can't be stored in one (scalar) variable simultaneously.

```
jQuery.get("ChkNewRspLive.php?lastmsgID=" + n, function(newitems){
    //some code to separate values of 2d array.
    var msgid = [],
        rspid = [];
    for( i = 0 ; i < newitems.length ; i++){
        msgid[msgid.length] = newitems[i][0];
        rspid[rspid.length] = newitems[i][1];
    }
    //msgid now contains ["320","310"]
    //rspid now contains ["23","26"]
});
```

Bear in mind those are in the function scope.  If you want to use them outside of that scope instantiate them outside. [see: closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: I tested your code, and i tried to display it by $('#div1').append(rspid[1]); but the output is still blank.

Comment: zac I left out some closing brackets (fixed). See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/W5CPG/1/

Comment: If I redeclare var newitems = [["320","23"],["310","26"]]; it works. So I guess the variable newitems from jQuery.get is something wrong. Is it I cannot pass the array from other page to current page through jQuery directly?

Comment: Regarding the array on other page, if echo json_encode($Arraytest); the output is [["320","23"],["310","26"]] but if echo $Arraytest; the output is Array. How do I pass the array from other page to currently page by jQuery.get?

Comment: I guess manybe because of jQuery.get get some white spaces from other page too? How to remove all white spaces?

Comment: what you described above is not json, or a javascript object, it's a javascript array. / Google those three terms.  If you are sending json, you should use JSON.parse on the javascript end https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse  or set the datatype to JSON in the get method (see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ ).


It looks like you've got some reading to do!  It looks like you might be missing some core PHP/JS knowledge; I suggest you read some intro texts like http://eloquentjavascript.net/ . Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pluck from underscore.js: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#pluck

```
var msgid = _(newitems).pluck(0)
var rspid = _(newitems).pluck(1)
```

Comment: @zac1987 you have to be using the underscore.js library.
@Craig that's pretty neat!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getArrayDimension(arr, dim) {
  var res = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    res.push(arr[i][dim]);
  }
  return res;
}

var newitems = [["320","23"],["310","26"]];
var msgid = getArrayDimension(newitems, 0);
var rspid = getArrayDimension(newitems, 1);
```

msgid and rspid are arrays holding the 'nth' dimention.

Tnx